# Getting and passing data to/from a ReactJs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to set the message on an alert window and bring back a success or failure message from it depending on user's interactions when the "addSkill" action is called. I have the code for the alertmodal and the addskill action below:

Add skill action:

```
addSkill(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let id = guid();
    let skill_name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.skill_name).value.trim();
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.skill_name).value = '';
    ProfileDispatcher.dispatch({
      action: ADD_SKILL,
      new_skill: {
        name: skill_name
      }
    });
  }
```

AlertModal component

```
class AlertModal extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {

    if (this.props.show) {
        return (
        <div id="Backdrop" className={classnames('WindowBackdrop', this.props.color)}>
          <div className="WindowInnerBackdrop">
            <div id="AlertModal" className={classnames('Window', this.props.size, this.props.align)}>
              <h3 className="WindowHeading">{this.props.heading}</h3>
              <p>{this.props.message}</p>
               <div className="AlertModalFooter">
                 <button>Cancel</button>
                 <button>OK</button>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
};

export default AlertModal;
```

Comment: Are you using Flux or Redux? Just wondering.

Comment: I am using the Flux approach

Comment: Did you register an action handler in your store to handle your `ADD_SKILL` action?

Comment: //Store: addSkill(new_skill){
    this.profile.skills.push(new_skill);
  },
// Register: 
case ADD_SKILL:
      ProfileStore.addSkill(new_skill);
      break

Comment: Your modal should register a change listener with the store that contains your skills. When this store changes, it can decide whether or not to show itself and what to show. Take a look at how this [example does it](http://spapas.github.io/2015/07/02/comprehensive-react-flux-tutorial-2/) - take a look at the stores.js and components.js implementations specifically.

Or, if you don't want to tightly couple the `AlertModal` to skills, you could have an intermediate listener component of some kind that creates and controls an AlertModal when the store changes.